# Why isn't Docker opening a port? (using Maven Grizzly Jenkins Blue-Ocean )

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, grizzly

Modifying one of the tutorials in the jenkins/blue-ocean tutorial for java to create a webapp.

Jenkinsfile contains:

```
docker {
  image 'maven:3-alpine'
  args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2 -p 8050:8050'
}

stage('Deliver') { 
        steps {
            sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver.sh' 
        }
}
```

while deliver.sh contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
mvn exec:java
echo 'Done!'
```

When it runs, the pipeline log shows:

```
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:8050]
Mar 22, 2018 7:26:10 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
Jersey app started with WADL available at http://localhost:8050/myapp/application.wadl
Hit enter to stop it...
```

but the command `netstat -atun | grep LISTEN`
doesn't show 8050, and trying to access it from a browser yields nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running on Linux then docker will most likely be running in a virtual machine. Run

```
docker-machine ip
```

to get the IP address of the VM and use that in the URL, e.g. http://192.168.99.100:8050/myapp/application.wadl